# Populate emails from Inbox to a listbox faster way

Tags: sql, vba, loops, outlook, listbox

I have the following scenario. Populate a `listbox1` with emails from `InBox`. I am using the
followings approach (Loop'For Each' and Sql '1 to count'):

LOOP

```
Sub Example_LOOP()

    Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace: Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim textDisplay As String
    Dim resultReceived  As String
    
    
    Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    
    For Each Item In olFolder.Items
        If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMail = Item
            textDisplay = oMail.Sender & " | " & oMail.Subject & " | " & oMail.ReceivedTime
            resultReceived = textDisplay & "§" & resultReceived
            
        End If
    Next

    With Me.ListBox1
        .Clear
        .List = Split(resultReceived, "§")
        .RemoveItem (Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1)
   End With
    
End Sub
```

and SQL:

```
Public Sub Example_SQL()
        
            Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace: Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
            Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
            Dim Items As Outlook.Items
        
            Dim Item As Object
            Dim i As Long
            Dim Filter As String
            Dim textDisplay As String
            Dim resultReceived  As String
        
            
            Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname" & _
                               Chr(34) & "Like ''"
            
        
            Set Items = olFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter)
                Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", 1
                
        
            For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
                If TypeOf Items(i) Is MailItem Then
                    Set Item = Items(i)
                    textDisplay = Item.Sender & " | " & Item.Subject & " | " & Item.ReceivedTime
                    resultReceived = textDisplay & "§" & resultReceived
                End If
            Next
            
        
            With Me.ListBox1
                .Clear
                .List = Split(resultReceived, "§")
                .RemoveItem (Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1)
           End With
End Sub
```

Reading 10000 emails takes around 45 seconds. It is possibility to do it faster. Or maybe a different approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.table) from the Outlook object model where you can specify only properties you are interested in. So, instead of loading in the loop each item from a folder you may iterate over rows in a table which I think can be much faster.

The [Folder.GetTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.gettable) method obtains a `Table` object that contains items filtered by `Filter`. By default, `TableContents` is `olUserItems` and the returned `Table` contains only the filtered items that are not hidden. If `Filter` is a blank string or the `Filter` parameter is omitted, `GetTable` returns a `Table` with rows representing all the items in the `Folder`.

`GetTable` returns a Table with the default column set for the folder type of the parent `Folder`. To modify the default column set, use the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.columns.add), [Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.columns.remove), or [RemoveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.columns.removeall) methods of the `Columns` collection object. You can use [Table.Restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.table.restrict) to apply subsequent filters to a Table that is based on the Folder object. For example:

```
Sub DemoTable()  
    'Declarations  
    Dim Filter As String  
    Dim oRow As Outlook.Row  
    Dim oTable As Outlook.Table  
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder  
  
    'Get a Folder object for the Inbox  
    Set oFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
  
    'Define Filter to obtain items last modified after May 1, 2021  
    Filter = "[LastModificationTime] > '5/1/2021'"  
    'Restrict with Filter  
    Set oTable = oFolder.GetTable(Filter)  
  
    'Enumerate the table using test for EndOfTable  
    Do Until (oTable.EndOfTable)  
        Set oRow = oTable.GetNextRow()  
        Debug.Print (oRow("Subject"))  
        Debug.Print (oRow("LastModificationTime"))  
    Loop  
End Sub`
```

Comment: It is fast... but seems that I can not add the email addresses. I only see those properties: { EntryID, Subject, CreationTime, LastModificationTime, MessageClass }. A workaround ?

Comment: Not supported if property is referenced by its explicit built-in name; but supported if property is referenced by its namespace.

Comment: What properties have you tried so far and which of them don't work for you?

Comment: For example: the email address from sender. I can not see how to be displayed.

Comment: Take a look at an item with OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy - click IMessage button). Select the property you need, see the DASL edit box.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Eugene's suggestion, do not load *all* items. Load them on demand as the user scrolls through the list.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this, and it is working fine (I can add only the properties that I'm looking for). Thanks to show me the direction. :)

```
Public Sub ExtractInBoxInfo()
    
        Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace: Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set oFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        Dim oTable As Outlook.Table
        Dim oRow As Outlook.Row
    
        Dim Filter As String
        Dim textDisplay As String
        Dim resultReceived  As String
    
        
       
        Filter = "[LastModificationTime] > '1/1/1900'"
    
        Set oTable = oFolder.GetTable(Filter)
        oTable.Columns.RemoveAll
            
        With oTable.Columns
            .Add ("SenderName")
            '.Add ("SenderEmailAddress")
            .Add ("Subject")
            .Add ("LastModificationTime")
        End With
    
        Do Until (oTable.EndOfTable)
            Set oRow = oTable.GetNextRow()
            textDisplay = oRow("SenderName") & " | " & oRow("Subject") & " | " & oRow("LastModificationTime")
            resultReceived = textDisplay & "§" & resultReceived
        Loop
        
    
        With Me.ListBox1
            .Clear
            .List = Split(resultReceived, "§")
            .RemoveItem (Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1)
       End With
    End Sub
```